# Merge text columns from different datafrm

Tags: r

In one dataframe I have 2 columns and one column into a second df.

I would like to take all rows from thee three columns into one column.

Merge like `test <- merge(df1$col1,df1$col2,df2$col2)` is not the right solution.

Any idea which is the right one?

Comment: Type `?cbind` in your R console

Comment: Do you really mean one column? Then try `c(df1$col1,df1$col2,df2$col2)`

Comment: @Jimbou the output has only numbers

Comment: @JakeKaupp why cbind? They don't have the same length. I try to make something like copy/paste the one down to other column

Comment: @Demlovat: sorry, on mobile and misread that.

Comment: then try `c(as.charachter(df1$col1),as.character(df1$col2),as.character(df2$col2))`

Comment: @Jimbou I receive this error `Error in as.charachter(df1$col1) : 
  could not find function "as.charachter"`

Comment: should be `as.character()` sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `rbindlist` from `data.table()`package

So first I created some data as an example:

```
# Three different vectors that will be converted to data frame with single column
a <- as.data.frame(c(1:3))
b <- as.data.frame(LETTERS[seq(1:4)])
c <- as.data.frame(1:10)

# Then I've used function rbindlist to row bind
rbindlist(list(a, b, c))

# And the output (one column with total number 17)

    c(1:3)
 1:      1
 2:      2
 3:      3
 4:      A
 5:      B
 6:      C
 7:      D
 8:      1
 9:      2
10:      3
11:      4
12:      5
13:      6
14:      7
15:      8
16:      9
17:     10
```

**UPDATE**

`rbindlist()` works with list, data.frames and data.tables, not with list of atomic types. So you need to edit your code like this `rbindlist(list(df1["col1"],df1["col2"],df2["col2"]))`

Comment: if you try to make it with dataframe columns do you receive an error like `Error in rbindlist(list(df1$col1,df1$col2,df2$col2)) : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list`

Comment: `rbindlist()` works with list, data.frames and data.tables, not with list of atomic types. So you need to edit your code like this `rbindlist(list(df1["col1"],df1["col2"],df2["col2"]))`

Answer (score 1):

In order to rbind the columns, they'll need to have the same number of rows:

```
df2$col2 <- NA # Ensures ncol(df2) == ncol(df1)
test <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: I think this option paste the three different cells into one. I would like i.e. first column has 3 rows, second 4 and third 10. Have one with total number 17